# How to count and group by column across one to many relationship while handling 0 case?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to formulate a single SQL query that will count a table across a one to many relationship. Here is the short version of my schema:

```
User(id)
Group(id)
UserGroup(user_id, group_id)
Post(id, user_id, group_id)
```

The goal is to return the count of posts for each user in a group. The specific issue I am running into is my current query cannot return 0 for a user that has no posts. Here is my naive query:

```
  SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as total, 
    user_id
  FROM 
    posts
  WHERE
    group_id = ?
  GROUP BY user_id
  ORDER BY
    total DESC
```

This works fine when every user has a post, but when some have no posts, they do not show up in the list. How can I write a single query that handles this scenario and returns count 0 for said users? I know I need to somehow incorporate `UserGroup` to get the list of users, but am stuck from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `left join`:

```
SELECT u.id, COUNT(*) as total
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     posts p
     ON p.user_id = u.id AND
        p.group_id = ?
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, but not sure how performant.

`select count(p), u.id from users u left join (select * from workouts where group_id = ?) p on p.user_id = u.id where u.id in (select user_id from user_group where group_id = ?) group by u.id;`